# Installing Gazebo2

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am running ROS indigo and trying to install Gazebo2.  Trying to follow these instructions: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_wrapper_versions

I have deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty main listed in my sources.

When I do an apt-cache search only gazebo5 shows up.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Matt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232945/installing-gazebo2/) by [Droter](https://answers.ros.org/users/2350/droter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2016-04-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-04-26**:
I checked the repository and confirmed that the gazebo2 deb is present in the repo and it's listed in the Packages file. I have also confirmed that gazebo2 appears when I do an apt-cache search on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

**Comment by [Droter](https://answers.ros.org/users/2350/droter/) on 2016-04-26**:
is it different if I am on an arm processor?

**Comment by [Droter](https://answers.ros.org/users/2350/droter/) on 2016-04-26**:
I can see gazebo5-common and gazebo5-doc and that is all

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-04-26**:
ARM is significantly different. There are no armhf debs for gazebo2 in the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No armhf debs for gazebo2 in repository.

Thanks ahendrix

---

Originally posted by [Droter](https://answers.ros.org/users/2350/droter/) with karma: 90 on 2016-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0